# Common tangent line to two functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have two functions:
$$f(x) = x^2 + 3$$
$$g(x) = -x^2 - 2x - 2$$

This two functions have a common tangent line that its slope is positive.

#### My approach:

$$f'(x) = 2x$$
$$g'(x) = -2x -2$$

I mark the two tangent points $x=a$ in $f(x)$  and $x = b$ in $g(x)$
$$(a, a^2 + 3)\qquad(b, -b^2 - 2b - 2)$$
I place the chosen points in their respective derivatives and equal:
$$2a = -2b - 2$$
$$a + b = -1$$
For trying to find the slope I do this:
\begin{align}
m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} & = \frac{a^2 + 3 + b^2 + 2b + 2}{a - b}\\
& = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2b + 5}{a - b}\\
\end{align}

I'm stuck here. What can I do to resolve my problem?

Comment: Almost finished. The slope $m$ you wrote down is equal to $2a$. That gives a reasonably nice equation. Substitute $b=-a-1$ and solve the resulting quadratic.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got that the slope is $\frac{2a^2 + 4}{2a+1}$ by putting $b = -a -1$ in the position of $b$ in the slope. How do you know that the slope is $2a$? Because of the derivative equation?

Comment: @AndréNicolas In $a^2 + a - 2 = 0$, $a = -2$ or $a=1$.

Comment: And yes, the common tangent line joins the points of tangency. So it has slope equal to the slope you computed earlier, $2a$ or equivalently $-2b-2$.

Comment: I am minus sign error prone, yes, those are the values.  Will delete comment with switched around signs so it will not confuse others.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! Now I understand. You can put this whole explanation as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You are welcome. Two answers have already been given, one of which has the same calculation. There is no need of another!

Comment: @AndréNicolas There isn't. Fine, no accepted answer haha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

You have $2a=-2b-2$

You also know that 
$$m = \frac{a^2 + 3 + b^2 + 2b + 2}{a - b}
 = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2b + 5}{a - b}=2a$$

You have two equations in two unknowns.  Solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

If using parametrizations :

The 2 functions are parametriezd by : $$c_1(t)=(t,f(t))=(t,t^2+3)$$
and $$c_2(T)=(T,g(T))=(T,-T^2-2T-2)$$
the tangent vectors are respectively $$c'_1(t)=(1,2t)$$
and $$c'_2(T)=(1,-2T-2)=(1,2(-T-1))$$
the two parametrizations of the two tangent lines are equivalent by the diffeomorphisme $$t=\phi(T)=-T-1$$
so they represent the same curve (tangent line) or the two functions have a common tangent.

Comment: Sorry but this is too complicated to me. Many things I haven't learned. Can you answer my answer in the same process as I did?

Comment: @Pichi Wuana  I'm sorry

Comment: It's okay hehe :-)